# How to convert Strftime into string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, strftime

I want to parse this strftime into a string, then just isolate the day variable.

```
 '2015-04-15T11:15:34'
```

I know in python, you could do something like:

```
 datetime.strptime(element, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

after importing something like:

```
 from datetime import datetime
 from datetime import timedelta
```

Is there a module or function in Ruby that can do this efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's also called `strptime`. http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime

> Parses the given representation of date and time with the given template, and creates a date object. strptime does not support specification of flags and width unlike strftime.
>
> `DateTime.strptime('2001-02-03T04:05:06+07:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z') 
>    #=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T04:05:06+07:00 ...>`

After including the required `date` library, you could then call `#day` on the resulting DateTime object to get the day. eg.

```
irb(main):016:0> require 'date'
=> true
irb(main):017:0> date = DateTime.strptime('2015-04-15T11:15:34', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
=> #<DateTime: 2015-04-15T11:15:34+00:00 ((2457128j,40534s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):018:0> date.day
=> 15
```

Comment: Will this be able to handle everything after the date like hours, mins, seconds i.e. ...'T11:15:34'?   I don't mind dropping this info either.  It's currently in a hash where time is the key.

Comment: @Codestudio yes, it will, if you use `DateTime.strptime` instead of `Date.strptime`. Updated answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateTime.iso8601` if you know the format is iso8601, otherwise you can use `DateTime.parse` which also handles a few other conventions.

```
2.2.1 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 
2.2.1 :002 > dt = DateTime.parse('2015-04-15T11:15:34')
 => #<DateTime: 2015-04-15T11:15:34+00:00 ((2457128j,40534s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
2.2.1 :003 > dt.year
 => 2015 
2.2.1 :004 > dt.month
 => 4 
2.2.1 :005 > dt.day
 => 15 
2.2.1 :006 > dt.hour
 => 11 
2.2.1 :007 > dt.zone
 => "+00:00"
```